# (PHP) How to order a multi dimensonal array with strings related to a variable?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, ajax

Hey I have a new feature on my website where you can
search for ya items by entering some keywords in the search input. Of course I am using ajax and I need a new function which sort or order the array which holds the item info from the database related to the keyword which the user writes in the input field.
When the user hits for example "**m**" so it should be displayed in this way.

```
array [["836","123","Malaga - Ocean","1"],
       ["834","123","Malaga City","1"],
       ["838","123","DayZ - Novo Turm #1","0"],
       ["839","123","DayZ - Novo Turm #2","0"],
       ["840","123","DayZ - Novo Turm #3","0"]]
```

But if Im searching for something which begins with the letter "**m**", "Malaga City" and "Malaga - Ocean" should be displayed first in the result.

I am searching more then one table for the keyword where I collect it. But if I am adding the array in every different table results I get so every time the picture table results first.

MySql:

```
$sql_picture = "SELECT * FROM pictures [...] ORDER BY name LIMIT 5";
$sql_videos = "SELECT * FROM videos [...] ORDER BY name LIMIT 5";
$sql_audio = "SELECT * FROM audio [...] ORDER BY name LIMIT 5";
$sql_documents = "SELECT * FROM documents [...] ORDER BY name LIMIT 5";
```

PHP:

```
$collectedDataName = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($collectData); $i++){
    $collectedDataName[$i] = $collectData[$i][2];
}

$collectData_lowercase = array_map('strtolower', $collectedDataName);

array_multisort($collectData_lowercase, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $collectedDataName);

$returnData = array();

for($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($collectData); $i++){
        if($collectData[$i][2] === $collectedDataName[$j]){
            $returnData[$j] = $collectData[$i];
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($returnData);
```

Result:

```
array [["838","123","DayZ - Novo Turm #1","0"],
      ["839","123","DayZ - Novo Turm #2","0"],
      ["840","123","DayZ - Novo Turm #3","0"],
      ["836","123","Malaga - Ocean","1"],
      ["834","123","Malaga City","1"]]
```

**How can I sort my multi dimensonal array by its string value related to a variable?**

Comment: Why can't you do an ORDER BY in your SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to sort your multi dimensional array based on the input value, a little bit like we do in sql using

```
select * from table where column like 'inputValue%'
```

This is a solution based on php only

```
$inputvalue = 'm';
$inputvalue = strtolower($inputvalue);

$collectData = [["838","123","DayZ - Novo Turm #1","0"],
             ["834","123","Malaga City","1"],
             ["839","123","DayZ - Novo Turm #2","0"],         
             ["836","123","Malaga - Ocean","1"],
             ["840","123","DayZ - Novo Turm #3","0"],
            ];

/*
we use strpos to check if the input value is contained in the strings array, if not we use levenshtein to calculate the distance between them.*/

$distances = array();
$positions = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($collectData); $i++) {    
  $current_val = strtolower($collectData[$i][2]);
  if (strpos($current_val, $inputvalue)!==false)
    $distance = strpos($current_val, $inputvalue);
  else
    $distance = levenshtein($inputvalue, $current_val);

  $distances[] = $distance;        
  $positions[] = array("distance"=>$distance, "position"=>$i);        
}

/*we sort distances*/
sort($distances);

/* we reorder collectData based on distances sort  */
$returnData = array();
for ($j=0; $j<count($distances); $j++) {
  for ($k=0; $k<count($positions); $k++) {
    $val = $collectData[$positions[$k]["position"]];

    if ($distances[$j]==$positions[$k]["distance"] && !in_array($val, $returnData)) {
        $returnData[] = $val;
        break;
    }
  }
}

return $returnData;
```

levenshtein php doc here : [levenshtein function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

Comment: this works fine so far, I will see tomorrow closer to your code and have a better look at to know what you did exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Could `array_multisort` Help? Are you meant to be returning results that only begin with "m"?

```
<?php
// create an array of the "column" to sort on...
foreach ($returnData as $row)  
{
    $test[] = $row[2];
}

// sort it...
array_multisort($test, SORT_DESC, $returnData);
?>
```

Comment: nope as you can see it will response items first which begins with an other letter.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential solutions to your problem:

**1. SQL Solution**

Have the database do the sorting for you by using a union.  For example:

```
SELECT
   id1, 
   id2,
   name
FROM
   (
       (SELECT id1, id2, name FROM pictures WHERE something=... ORDER BY name LIMIT 5)
       UNION ALL
       (SELECT id1, id2, name FROM videos WHERE something=... ORDER BY name LIMIT 5)
    ) AS q
ORDER BY
   name
```

**2. PHP Solution**

You are doing a non-standard sort, so you need to use `usort` which takes a comparator function that compares two array items:

```
$allData = array_merge($sql_picture, $sql_video, ...);
usort($allData, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a[2], $b[2]); });
```

Comment: I also want to union my 4 table sql request but I failed doing it. So i provisionally build something else to reach my aim in an other way. How I am doing it?

Comment: Couse for real I didnt get the syntax how you write in your answere. It seams more complicated as normal resquests.

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML I edited it slightly to show where you put your WHERE clause.  I don't know the names of your fields but change id1 and id2 to whatever is in your database.

Comment: And there are only two table requests how im going on. Adding more?

Comment: Add more UNION ALL (SELECT ... )

Comment: What does the `AS q` mean?

Comment: MySQL requires that all subqueries have a name.  I arbitrarily chose "q" as the name.

Comment: I got an error but can you check out the syntax please, https://jsfiddle.net/k21o2v8r/1/

Comment: There are two problems: 1. You have an extra `UNION ALL` - that is your syntax error.  2. You should never ever inline a PHP variable containing user data in your SQL (in you case using $userInput) as it opens you up to SQL Injection attacks.  A full discussion of SQL injection outside the scope of this answer - please read http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php.

Comment: `$userInput = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET["userInput"]);`
Doesn't this make it? I also do know about injections and so on. So I removed the extra one but the error is still there.

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML I suggest prepared statements which are safer. If this answered your original question please accept the answer.